# Removing specific values from array with some condition using jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, unique

I have below array

```
    var myArr = [
"01;#Sion",
"02;#Sion",
"03;#Mumbai",
"04;#Mumbai",
"05;#Kolkata",
"06;#Kolkata",
"07;#Chennai",
"08;#Chennai"
];
```

I need output in array as:

```
["01;#Sion", "03;#Mumbai", "05;#Kolkata", "07;#Chennai"]
```

It should select only unique values after `;#` .

For Sion, output can be `"01;#Sion"` or `"02;#Sion"`.
Any of them is fine.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
var myArr = ["01;#Sion", "02;#Sion", "03;#Mumbai", "04;#Mumbai", "05;#Kolkata", "06;#Kolkata", "07;#Chennai", "08;#Chennai"];
var newArr = [];

for (j = 0; j < myArr.length; j++) {
    newArr.push(myArr[j].split(";#")[1]);
}

newArr = NWF$.unique(newArr);

console.log(newArr); // -> ["Chennai", "Kolkata", "Mumbai", "Sion"]
```

Comment: So what did you try?

Comment: $.unique tried, but it yields all 8 outputs.

Comment: Of course it will - they ARE all unique. You need to do some string-handling, processing. If you show an effort, people are more likely to help.

Comment: [`$.unqiue()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.unique/): "_Sorts an array of DOM elements, in place, with the duplicates removed. **Note that this only works on arrays of DOM elements, not strings or numbers**._"

Comment: I tried splitting each value by ;# and then I got unique values, but, afterwards stuck how to add either '01' or '02' to the 'Sion' value in code.

Comment: Show the split code you tried. This isn't a free coding service...we help you fix **your code**

Comment: Here it is:

`var myArr = ["01;#Sion","02;#Sion","03;#Mumbai","04;#Mumbai","05;#Kolkata","06;#olkata","07;#Chennai","08;#Chennai"];var newArr = [];for(j=0;j<myArr.length;j++){ newArr.push(myArr[j].split(";#")[1]);}newArr = NWF$.unique(newArr);`


Output of `newArr` is:
`["Chennai", "Kolkata", "Mumbai", "Sion"]`

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution mate,

```
var myArr = ["01;#Sion", "02;#Sion", "03;#Mumbai", "04;#Mumbai", "05;#Kolkata", "06;#Kolkata", "07;#Chennai", "08;#Chennai"];
var newArr = [];
var tempArr = [];
for (j = 0; j < myArr.length; j++) {
    newArr.push(myArr[j].split(";#")    [1]);
    tempArr.push(myArr[j]);
}
var temp = '';
var result = [];
for(i=0;i<newArr.length;i++){
    if(temp == '' || temp != newArr[i]){
       temp = newArr[i];
       result.push(tempArr[i]);
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

Here is working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/swapper8/s3p4ks1x/2/)

Give it a try, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest ways to do something like this is create a temporary object where the property names are the values you want to compare.

For your case, if a property doesn't exist yet you add it otherwise you skip it

Once object is complete, iterate all it's properties to create new array

```js
var myArr = [
   "01;#Sion",
   "02;#Sion",
   "03;#Mumbai",
   "04;#Mumbai",
   "05;#Kolkata",
   "06;#Kolkata",
   "07;#Chennai",
   "08;#Chennai"
 ];

 var tmp = {};
 myArr.forEach(function(el) {
   var city = el.split('#')[1];
   if (!tmp[city]) {
     tmp[city] = el;
   }
 });

 console.log('tmp', tmp); 

 var newArr = Object.keys(tmp).map(function(key) {
   return tmp[key];
 });

 console.log('newArr', newArr)
```